# neo4j-import not importing nodes into database

Tags: import, neo4j, nodes

I'm working on importing product information into a database using the neo4j-import tool, and finding that the nodes imported are not showing up in the database. The initial command:

> ./neo4j-import --into t8 --nodes:Product ../../productheader.csv,../../products_asinonly.csv

the end of the output:

> IMPORT DONE in 1m 417ms. Imported:   9430088 nodes   0 relationships
>   9430088 properties Peak memory usage: 202.20 MB

After which, I change the active database in neo4j.conf, restart the neo4j server and open the site in the browser. My problem is found here:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
(no rows)
```

Why can I not find the 9 million nodes it says it just imported? I've triple checked that I'm pointing at the right database, and this works with other data.